# In what situation would document.open() return null?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, internet-explorer-6

I'm trying to understand an intermittent script error that I am seeing in a JavaScript intensive thin-client application running under Internet Explorer 6 and Windows XP.  The root cause of the problem is that the following function call returns a `null` value (however it does succeed without an error):

```
var doc = targetWindow.document.open("text/html","_replace");
```

Where `targetWindow` is a [window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object.

Neither `targetWindow` nor `targetWindow.document` is `null` and so I'm struggling to understand why this call would return `null`.  My interpretation of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is that this method shouldn't ever return null.

This code has been unchanged and working perfectly for many years - until I understand why this is happening I'm not sure either how I might handle this, or what might have changed to cause this to start happening.

What might cause this function call to return null?

Comment: Is it possible to stop supporting IE6? After all, Microsoft doesn't even support it anymore. Plus, IE8 works on Windows XP just fine. If it's a corporate environment, you should convince them to finally upgrade away from the insecurities, flaws and limitations of IE6.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you should be passing "replace", not "_replace". Try this instead:

```
var doc = targetWindow.document.open("text/html", "replace");
```

Since you say your code has worked for years, then it is likely that something has changed and the above suggestion may not be the issue. However, it is still worth a try.

Have you changed any js files / libraries you are using in your application lately? Also, are you using any browser plugins within the page? It is possible that a newer version of either of these could be somehow affecting your call to "document.open".

Answer (score 0):

document.open() does not have any parameters by W3C standard. Check out this link: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-72161170

I recommend you to use W3C documentation instead of Microsoft's one because with W3C you are sure it works on all modern browsers, while Microsoft is well known for adding extensions that, of course, works only in their own products. It's called EEE (Embrace, extend and extinguish).

Simply use document.open() without arguments. There are ways to manipulate user history, but that's called bad programming practice. History is user's private data and web application should not try to manipulate it.

Comment: Normally I would wholeheartedly support this, but the OP is maintaining an application that (as I read it) *only* runs on IE6, in which case this answer is almost entirely useless. The little rant about EEE just makes it worse.